# Create a hashing list in scala using Map

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, hash

I am trying to create a map in scala

`var map1:Map[String,List[String]]` from a list of tuples

`input : List(("a1",1),("a1",2),("b1",3),("c1",2),("c1",3),("c1",4))`

`def fn(List[String]):` which takes input as List of tuples and globally declared Map is updated and finally result Map with Value Lists.

```
output : Map(a1->[1,2], b1->[3], c1->[2,3,4])
```

How to create a function that can achieve the same by first searching key and appending in the value list.

Comment: Mutating a globally defined map is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code for your logic, which accepts list of tuples as input and returns value Map with key and value list.

```
import scala.collection.immutable._

//function which accepts List of Tuples and returns Map
def convertListToMap(inputParam:List[(String, Int)]) : Map[String,List[Int]]={
  inputParam.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
}

//List of Tuples as inputs
val input=List(("a1",1),("a1",2),("b1",3),("c1",2),("c1",3),("c1",4))
//List((a1,1), (a1,2), (b1,3), (c1,2), (c1,3), (c1,4))

//invoking convertListToMap
convertListToMap(input)
//Output:  Map(a1 -> List(1, 2), c1 -> List(2, 3, 4), b1 -> List(3))

// remaining logic to proceed further
```

Comment: It would be good to mention that in `2.13` you can use `groupMap(_._1)(_._2)`

Comment: thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, using `2.11` for this logic.